# Preventing some information from changing in chatGPT model

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using chatgpt3.5 turbo model and I want to fine-tune it on my set of questions and answers. it is working perfectly except for some parts.
in my answers, I have some information like names of individuals, their email addresses, phone numbers and so on which I do not want them to change. but when I fine-tune my model and use it, it always changes this information. how can I prevent this from happening?

for example, if I ask the model “who has fine-tuned you?” I want to get this answer: “Masoud has done this part and his phone number is 123456789.” I do not want “Masoud” and “123456789” change to something else.

this is my code:

```
import os
import openai
import time 

openai.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

file = openai.File.create(
  file=open("fine_tuning.jsonl", "rb"),
  purpose='fine-tune'
)
# Retrieve the file ID.
file_id = file.id

# Print the file ID.
print(file_id)

job = openai.FineTuningJob.create(training_file=file_id, model="gpt-3.5-turbo")

 

# Get job ID.
job_id = job.id

# Poll the status of the fine-tuning job in a loop until it succeeds.
while True:
    # Retrieve the job details using the correct job ID.
    retrieved_job = openai.FineTuningJob.retrieve(id=job_id)

    # Print the current status of the fine-tuning job.
    print(f"Current status: {retrieved_job.status}")
    print("Error details:", retrieved_job.error)

    # Check if the job has succeeded.
    if retrieved_job.status == "succeeded":
        # Get the name of the fine-tuned model.
        fine_tuned_model_name = retrieved_job.fine_tuned_model

        # Print the name of the fine-tuned model.
        print(f"Fine-tuned model name: {fine_tuned_model_name}")
        break  # Exit the loop since the job has succeeded.

    # Wait for a few seconds before checking the status again.
    time.sleep(5)
```